# Replace eregi() with preg_match() syntax error

Tags: php, syntax, preg-match, eregi

I have lines of php code that I need to change

```
while (eregi("([-]?)\"([^\"]+)\"", $a, $regs)) {
```

to

```
while (preg_match("([-]?)\"([^\"]+)\"", $a, $regs)) {
```

and

```
if (strlen($word) < $min_word_length || (!eregi($pattern, remove_accents($word))) || ($common[$word] == 1)) {
```

to

```
if (strlen($word) < $min_word_length || (!preg_match($pattern, remove_accents($word))) || ($common[$word] == 1)) {
```

I tried all possible(I can) combinations, I searched on google and here also but can't figure it out.

Comment: you did not use the delimiters.... you can see the manual   http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php. try  this "/([-]?)\"([^\"]+)\"/"

Comment: @laurac thank you for your suggestion, your written line just worked perfectly. Can you please write the second line also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not use the delimiters.... 
you can see the manual [php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

try this "/([-]?)\"([^\"]+)\"/" (i'm only adding the "/" at the beginning and the end of the string "/$pattern/" )

```
if (strlen($word) < $min_word_length || (!preg_match("/$pattern/", remove_accents($word))) || ($common[$word] == 1)) {
```

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. But you are great and saved a lot of time for me. Really thank you very much.